# Singleton or static in class library

Tags: c#, static, asp.net-mvc-5, singleton

I have an ASP.net MVC 5 web application which is interacting with an external framework, actually it is a web interface for that application. My Application interacts with a wrapper of the SDK (app calls wrapper which it self calls sdk). The holistic view is depicted below:

[image: SDK Interaction]

Wrapper and SDK are two different class libraries. SDK is added as a reference to wrapper and the wrapper is added as a reference to web app.

For every user, an instance of wrapper and its associated sdk instance is created. So many functionalities need to be fulfilled through admin priviledges, which requires an always-running admin connection. Those functionalities are either implemented using quartz jobs (like caching list items, caching user info, clearing old connections etc.) or are used per user requests. So I thought we need a singleton admin instance. My current implementation uses a singleton instance in the wrapper, called first time in application initialization and having Quartz jobs in the web app. There are two questions to ask:

1. Since every user creates a wrapper object, is the singleton admin instance in there  a good choice?
2. Reqarding Quartz jobs in the web app, I need to have a static admin instance of wrapper inside the web app which seems not correct to me, (or instantiate this object per jobs call, as it is implemented right now), any chance to improve the situation?

Comment: If you want something only once in your dependency injection and your dependency injection calls that "singleton lifetime", that seems like a choice only you can make in the context of your application. But I see no reason in this whole project to have a singleton pattern implemented.

Comment: `static` types are hard to test, so that might be the deciding factor in the end, if there really is a choice to be made.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you posting as much of your code as possible as it will highlight what exactly you are asking.

My understanding of your question would push me towards the best practice of setting up dependency injection as supported in MVC 5 as should here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

This means setting up a singleton which you pass to controllers as a dependency. There are a few benefits of singletons over static classes in this case, e.g. it will allow you to use interfaces down the line if your application starts to grow. Typically I only use static functions or classes for immutable code with no state, not sure if this is the consensus of the programming community but it makes sense syntax wise.

As for your connections, check the best practices for if you should keep connections alive in the tools you are using. This may be different across different SDK or tools, e.g. MySQL recommends connection pools for scalable web applications.

It may also be an option for you to create the admin instance as one dependency and then open the user connections as required from a separate user service

Disclaimer: I don't know what a Quartz job is but after a quick google search it  seems like a singleton, using MVC 5 dependency injection, configured to use connection pools is the answer you are after
https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/wiki/How-to-Use-DB-Connection-Pool